# Is it possible to view source code of an API class?

Tags: java, api, source-code-protection

E.g I'd like to see how Integer Class is coded. Is that available?

Comment: Yes. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java

Comment: what sort of api class any eg..?

Comment: Integer class. Where to find it?

Comment: @Square-root Did you click on the link given ?

Comment: awesome. thanks alot

Comment: An IDE will usually also be able to show that, when you do "Go To Definition" (or similar) on `Integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install `JDK`, there is an option to install the sources, which is selected by default.

[image: jdk installation]

After installing, when you open a project, IDEs will usually automatically index Java sources. If not, you can attach the sources to your project depending on your IDE.

Alternatively, you open `<JDK_HOME>\src.zip` and see the Java sources.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using some IDE.To attach the Java source code with Eclipse(for example), When you install the JDK, you must have selected the option to install the Java source files too Or you can refer below think to attach.

### See Also

- [Attach java source in Eclipse.](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/08/eclipse-how-attach-java-source.html)